# Error - running spookyjs

Tags: node.js, windows, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I am getting the following error in `windows` while running `spookyjs` but code is working in `linux`.

#### Error

```
events.js:85
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: spawn casperjs ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (ch
at child_process.js:1137:20
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

#### Note:

I have installed all the dependencies and added the `PATH` varaiables

1. Phantomjs
2. Python
3. casperjs - Installed globally using `npm install -g casperjs`

In the command prompt `casperjs` is working

### What I have tried:

1. Installed npm as global using

   ```
    npm install -g npm
   ```
2. Uninstalled `0.12` and downgraded to `0.10`.
3. Added System variable `C:\Windows\System32;`.

Any idea or suggestion will be grateful

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`spawn` is trying to execute the `casperjs` command, make sure you can execute it from your `cmd.exe` console. If this is not executing locate the `casperjs` binary and make sure it's added to the `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Any update? I have the same issue.

Both phantomjs & casperjs are in the PATH and work from cmd.exe. Tried to install it globally too...

I'm running out of options!

EDIT: OK I didn't test this but it makes sense. Apparently spawn can't handle .bat and .cmd files, hence why it does work from cmd.exe but not from spawn when PhantomJS and CasperJS are installed via npm. Installing them manually should work because you'll have phantomjs.exe and casperjs.exe. Gonna try it tonight.

EDIT2: Yep. Works. Install them manually (and put the new path in the PATH variable) and you're good to go.

Comment: what do you mean by "install them manually" I downloaded the folders both casper and phatom from their respectives sites and they do not have an installer so I just placed the two folders on C:/ and added the path to my Path enviroment variable. Still not working, what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Actually spawn is execute casperjs cmd you in windows.In linux you were using like this

> var casperjs = spawn('casperjs', [__dirname+'******', username]);

but in windows if you have installed casperjs globally try this

> var casperjs = spawn('casperjs.cmd', [__dirname+'******', username]);

or give full path in spawn("full installation path")

For me this is working on windows hopefully this will help you too.